# asynchronous programming without asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I want to write a Python program that demonstrates the use of generators and asynchronous programming concepts such as send, yield from, and yield. Program should perform a specific asynchronous task using only these features without relying on external libraries such as asyncio, multithreading, or async/await syntax.

I wrote image downloader but it is working synchronously for some reason, how may I fix it ?

```
import time
import urllib.request

delays = iter((4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5))


def download_file(url, filename):
    delay = next(delays)
    time.sleep(delay)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(filename, 'wb') as out_file:
        data = response.read()
        out_file.write(data)
    print(f'{filename} downloaded, delay {delay}')


def async_downloader(files):
    for url, filename in files:
        yield download_file(url, filename)


def run_async_downloader(files):
    async_gen = async_downloader(files)
    while True:
        try:
            async_gen.send(None)
        except StopIteration:
            break


FILES = [
    ['http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3488/4051378654_238ca94313.jpg', 'n00004475_42770.jpg'],
    ['http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3368/3198142470_6eb0be5f32.jpg', 'n00004475_54295.jpg'],
    ['http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3276/2875184020_9944005d0d.jpg', 'n00004475_15899.jpg'],
    ['http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4094333885_e8462a8338.jpg', 'n00004475_32312.jpg'],
    ['http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3289/2809605169_8efe2b8f27.jpg', 'n00004475_35466.jpg']
]

run_async_downloader(FILES)
```

Comment: `urllib.request.urlopen(url)` is synchronous, it downloads the whole file, so you run the downloads one by one in sync code. The operating system level way of doing async reading is with select, at least with a raw socket you can do that. https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html

Comment: Your program is running sequentially because you are using neither threads nor Processes nor asyncio.  Despite what you say, `send`, `yield from` and `yield` are not asynchronous programming concepts.  They are the tools used by asyncio, but that is an implementation detail and is not required by the concepts of asynchronous programming.  Also, asyncio, threading and async/await syntax are not "external libraries" but part of the Python standard library.  They are no more "external" than `yield` or `yield from`.

Answer (score 0):

The code below uses a technique described in section 12.12 of the ["Python Cookbook"](https://github.com/lemon123456/Books/blob/master/Python%20Cookbook%2C%203rd%20Edition.pdf) providing a general facility for running multiple "asynchronous" tasks concurrently by abstracting the notion of an asynchronous task.

By using the `requests` package, we can download each file in chunks as they become available. This will allow some degree of concurrency.

```py
import requests

def download_file(session, url, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as out_file:
        yield
        r = session.get(url, stream=True)
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=None):
            print(f'writing chunk of size {len(chunk)} to {filename}', flush=True)
            yield
            out_file.write(chunk)

from collections import deque

class TaskScheduler:
    def __init__(self):
        self._task_queue = deque()

    def new_task(self, task):
        '''
        Admit a newly started task to the scheduler
        '''
        self._task_queue.append(task)

    def run(self):
        '''
        Run until there are no more tasks
        '''
        while self._task_queue:
            task = self._task_queue.popleft()
            try:
                # Run until the next yield statement
                next(task)
                self._task_queue.append(task)
            except StopIteration:
                # Generator is no longer executing
                pass

FILES = [
    ['http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3488/4051378654_238ca94313.jpg', 'n00004475_42770.jpg'],
    ['http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3368/3198142470_6eb0be5f32.jpg', 'n00004475_54295.jpg'],
    ['http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3276/2875184020_9944005d0d.jpg', 'n00004475_15899.jpg'],
    ['http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4094333885_e8462a8338.jpg', 'n00004475_32312.jpg'],
    ['http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3289/2809605169_8efe2b8f27.jpg', 'n00004475_35466.jpg']
]

sched = TaskScheduler()
session = requests.Session()
for url, filename in FILES:
    sched.new_task(download_file(session, url, filename))
sched.run()
```

Prints:

```None
writing chunk of size 36969 to n00004475_42770.jpg
writing chunk of size 49422 to n00004475_54295.jpg
writing chunk of size 16378 to n00004475_15899.jpg
writing chunk of size 8943 to n00004475_32312.jpg
writing chunk of size 22386 to n00004475_35466.jpg
writing chunk of size 14351 to n00004475_15899.jpg
writing chunk of size 52222 to n00004475_32312.jpg
writing chunk of size 4447 to n00004475_35466.jpg
writing chunk of size 12786 to n00004475_35466.jpg
writing chunk of size 6396 to n00004475_35466.jpg
writing chunk of size 7966 to n00004475_35466.jpg
```